# Microsoft Report Builder - Layout. Building a table of labels

Tags: sql, layout, reportbuilder, microsoft-reporting

I am currently trying to re-create a report to print the patient labels for armbands for the daily clinic.

I am to print to a  sticky label page with three columns and eleven rows for patient ids.

I have tried grouping my table via column or row to get the sequential ids, but I am unable to get the report to print the in multiple columns and rows, on the same page.

Example of layout I'm aiming for :
[image: Example of layout I'm aiming for.]
What my report currently looks like :
[image: What my report currently looks like.]

I am unable to make the ids sequential for both the columns and rows, and repeat on the next page if there are more than 33 patients (which there usually are). Not sure if this is a coding failure or I am missing something on the layout end.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the answer on a similar post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5ea22a88-d80c-4a86-ad4a-ed125fb46e84/printing-address-labels-using-report-builder

In the model of report builder I am using, in the Properties Side Window, under Report and Page there is a column number that can be modified. I set it to three, and now the report continues to print down the column and continues to the next on the same page.

Thank you to anyone who went out of their way to start researching this!